# C# Linq To Xml - How do Select collection of elements and modify each using lambda?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to select elements from XDocument and add an attribute to each in a single lambda expression. This is what I'm trying:

```
  xhtml.Root.Descendants()
            .Where(e => e.Attribute("documentref") != null)
            .Select(e => e.Add(new XAttribute("documenttype", e.Attribute("documentref").Value)));
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  xhtml.Root.Descendants()
            .Where(e => e.Attribute("documentref") != null)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(e => e.Add( new.... ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to the deferred execution of LINQ, if the results of the statement are never iterated through, the attributes will not get added to the XML.

```
var elementsWithAttribute = from e in xhtml.Root.Descendants()
                            let attribute = e.Attribute("documentref")
                            where attribute != null
                            select e;

foreach (var element in elementsWithAttribute)
    element.Add(...);
```